How to start a animation after mauiToolKit popup loads?
I'm trying to animate the scroll bar to scroll down after a specified time after the popup is loaded. Unfortunately, I can't find any useful method overrides like "AfterPageLoad()" or any events. I tried subscribing to the Opened event but it doesn't work at all
this.Opened += (s, e) => scrollMain.ScrollToAsync(0, 100, true);

Does anyone know how and when to start animation so it would appear on popup loaded?
Edit: updating the question with XAML code in which the crollView is placed
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mct:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Zaklad.ProductEditor"
             xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="True"
             x:Name="ThisPopup"
             Color="{StaticResource StandardBackground_Shade_1}"
             Size="400, 600">
    <mct:Popup.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <mct:MultiMathExpressionConverter x:Key="MultiMathExpressionConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </mct:Popup.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollView x:Name="scrollMain" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource StandardBackground_Shade_1}">
<Grid RowSpacing=10 Margin="10, 0, 10, 10" ...> <!--Whole Grid structure-->
        </ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="DecisionButtons" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Spacing="10" Margin="10" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <VerticalStackLayout.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold"/>

                </Style>
            </VerticalStackLayout.Resources>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>

</mct:Popup>


What is the scrollMain? And did you want to start the animation ather the popup shows?

scrollMain is the name of my <ScrollView/>. Yes, I want to start the animation after the popup is visible to the user, more specifically 1s after it is shown to the user.

Where is the ScrollView? Could you please post more code snippets so that we can help you better?
